# Given $P,Q$ with prime order, prove $P \cap Q$ is trivial group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $P,Q \leq G$ both have prime order, with $P \neq Q$. Prove
>   that $P \cap Q$ is the trivial group.

I think Sylow's theorem applies here but I feel like there is not enough information to make a statement about $P$ and $Q$. What's a good way to start showing $P \cap Q$ is the trivial group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $P \cap Q$ is a subgroup of both $P$ and $Q$, and hence its order divides both $|P|$ and $|Q|$. If $|P| \neq |Q|$, what can we conclude? If $|P| = |Q|$, what can we conclude using $P \neq Q$?